# trying to return a response using axios

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm trying to write an async function that returns the response from the find ISS API using axios.
What's happening is whatever I ty to return winds up as a pending promise.
If I try to access the information in the function with console.log that works

```
 async function apiCall(url)  {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response.status)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
console.log(apiCall("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json"))
```

and it logs

```
Promise { <pending> } 200
```

Comment: `console.log(await apiCall("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json"))`

Comment: `async` function always returns a promise. Any non-promise value is implicitly wrapped in a promise.